# getting currentPosition on videoView

Tags: macos, kotlin, android-videoview, onsaveinstancestate

I wrote a code for playing a video offline, but the problem is that when I rotate the screen, the video plays from the start again because currentPosition returns 0
It should be noted that I am using the Mac version of Android Studio

```
private fun initVideoView() {


    val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://$packageName/${R.raw.test_video2}")


    val mediaController = MediaController(this)


    try {
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
        videoView.start()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Error", e.message ?: "Error")
    }

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener {

        it.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener { _, _, _ ->
            mediaController.setAnchorView(binding.videoView)
        }

    }

}


override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)


    outState.putInt("position", this.videoView.currentPosition)

}


override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

    videoView.seekTo(savedInstanceState.getInt("position", 0))

}
```

Comment: Try calling the `super.onSaveInstanceState` after you made your changes. The super function is likely to handle the actual saving of the instance state